# Build <boost/thread/thread.hpp> for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, boost, boost-thread

From the documentation on the boost website, thread.hpp is not a header-only library, it needs to be built separately. I wonder how can I build thread.hpp separately?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, the easiest thing to do is to get boost from somewhere like [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=boost).

E.g. first install Homebrew:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

and then just:

```
$ sudo brew install boost
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: I did installed boost using macports. I just need to build boost.thread separately

Comment: OK - I think in the Homebrew package the libraries may already be built but I can't easily check just now.